# Hibernate Custom Basic Type with Database Function

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, user-defined-types

I'm making a custom Hibernate type using `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType` to automatically convert the SQL UDT into a Java type. The SQL uses database functions to construct and serialize the column data from BLOBs and/or CLOBs, and I want to hide that from a user. So they don't have to use `@ColumnTransformer(read="_serializer(column_name)", write="_constructor(?)")` for every column.

I've made types using the BLOB `SqlTypeDescriptor` and a custom `JavaTypeDescriptor` to do the conversion at the JDBC level, but how can I have my custom type wrap the column and parameters in the proper SQL functions? I'm not finding anything describing anything like this.

Edit:
To make this more concrete, this UDT (SDE [`ST_GEOMETRY`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm)) must be build via database functions ([`ST_LineFromText`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-linefromtext.htm)) or the defined UDT constructor ([`ST_LineString`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-linestring.htm)). Likewise, to read them from the database, you have to "export" them into a certain format ([`ST_AsText`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-astext.htm)) for Java to read it. The regular approach of reading the fields of the type doesn't work in this case.

So:

```sql
create table geo_lines (
  line SDE.ST_GEOMETRY
);
```

And:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="geo_lines")
public class GeoLine {
  @Column(name="line")
  @Type(type="org.example.MyStLineType")
  // i'm wanting to be able to omit the following annotation
  @ColumnTransformer(read="SDE.ST_AsText(line)", 
         write="SDE.ST_ST_LineFromText(?, 3857)")
  private Polyline line;
}
```

So, all my type really needs from the user is the number (`3857` in this case), which can be passed as a parameter, and everything else is standard boilerplate for any line. Repeat for the other types like points, polygons, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by saying `wrap the column and parameters in the proper SQL functions`?

Comment: Generally you can annotate the entity class getter with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "your.custom.DataType")`

Comment: Indeed. I haven't given you enough information. See edit.

Comment: Seems like this should work by what you've described, unless you want the `3857` to be a parameter. The `@ColumnTransformer(write)` must only have one question mark. It is checked by the regular expression in `org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column#initMappingColumn` function.